# OverflowError in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I am trying to run:

```
pd.to_datetime(15246544840000000000)
```

then I get the overflow error as the following:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

So I changed the number to a float as

```
pd.to_datetime(15246544840000000000.0)
```

The output becomes: `NaT`

I don't know what `NaT` is and why I cannot convert the float or integer number to a timestamp.

Comment: What is expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael Something like: `2018-04-25 11:08:04+00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide by `10 * 10` first and then (optional) pass `unit='s'`:

```
print (15246544840000000000 / 10 * 10)
1524654484.0

s = pd.to_datetime(15246544840000000000 / 10 * 10)
print (s)

2018-04-25 11:08:04
```

Comment: Well, nanoseconds is very small. I realize timestamp resolution is in seconds.

Comment: @HadiRouhani - I changed answer.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an efficient remedy when it comes to a column of a dataframe?

Comment: @HadiRohani - Sure, it is very efficient, also if column. Then need `pd.to_datetime(df['col'] / 10 ** 10, unit='s')`